# Play Framework 2.3.7 Ebean OneToMany relationships not updated

Tags: playframework, persistence, entity-relationship, ebean, playframework-2.3

I updated my project from play framework 2.1.x to 2.3.7. Now I have the following problem:

If I use the Model.update() method, the OneToMany relationships will not be updated. Example below:

```
@Entity
@CacheStrategy
public class Workshop extends Model {
    @Id
    public Long id;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    public List<WorkshopWholesaler> wholesalers;
}

@Entity
public class WorkshopWholesaler extends Model {
    @Id
    public Long id;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    @ManyToOne
    public Workshop workshop;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    @ManyToOne
    public Wholesaler wholesaler;
}

@Entity
@CacheStrategy
public class Wholesaler extends Model {
    @Id
    public Long id;
}
```

When I add a WorkshopWholesaler to the wholesalers list at workshop and use the update() method from workshop afterwards, the relation will not be saved to the database. What could be the problem? I use Ebean as persistence layer.

Comment: Each WorkshopWholesaler in the wholesalers list, is already in db ? Otherwise, this is the problem. The save is not propagated with Ebean ...

Answer (score 0):

You have to set both sides of relation. So not only add this new `WorkshopWholesaler` to wholesalers list but also set `workshop` property in this new object.

Comment: it is not necessary, the problem must be elsewhere